# Subsetting dataframe based on another vector/list/dataframe in R

Tags: r

**Code**
1.
`subset(df3, df.check$BREDS %in% df3$BREDS)`
2.
`df3[(df.check$BREDS %in% df3$BREDS),]`
3.
`df3 %>% filter(df.check$BREDS %in% df3$BREDS)`

Error:Must subset rows with a valid subscript vector
i Logical subscripts must match the size of the indexed input.
x The input has size 27204 but the subscript `i` has size 8.

Comment: I don't know what you are trying to show with 1, 2 and 3 but I think in all your attempts condition should be opposite `subset(df3, BREDS %in% df.check$BREDS)`

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. Actually that was the only issue.

Answer (score 0):

`%in%` returns output of the length of LHS. See for example,

```
1:10 %in% 1:4
#[1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
1:4 %in% 1:10
#[1] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

So if you reverse the arguments in all your attempts you should get what you were looking for.

1)

```
subset(df3, BREDS %in% df.check$BREDS)
```

2)

```
df3[df3$BREDS %in% df.check$BREDS,]
```

3)

```
library(dplyr)
df3 %>% filter(BREDS %in% df.check$BREDS)
```